# SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null

Tags: db2

What does sqlcode -302 means?
Where do i get the sqlcode definitions?

Please advice

Thanks,

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can find the codes in the DB2 Information Center.  [Here's a definition](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n302.html) of the `-302` from the z/OS Information Center:

> THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER position-number IS
> INVALID OR TOO LARGE FOR THE TARGET COLUMN OR THE TARGET VALUE

On Linux/Unix/Windows DB2, you'll look under [SQL Messages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/rsqlmsg.html) to find your error message. If the code is positive, you'll look for `SQLxxxxW`, if it's negative, you'll look for `SQLxxxxN`, where xxxx is the code you're looking up.

Comment: In encountered this in versino 10. Is there a way to find which column caused this? For DB2 version 10, explanation is here : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/n302.htm

Comment: If you look at the message that should come with the error, `THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR PARAMETER NUMBER position-number IS INVALID OR TOO LARGE FOR THE TARGET COLUMN OR THE TARGET VALUE`, `position-number` should give you the number of the column that is causing your troubles.

Answer (score 13):

To get the definition of the SQL codes, the easiest way is to use db2 cli!

at the unix or dos command prompt, just type

```
db2 "? SQL302"
```

this will give you the required explanation of the particular SQL code that you normally see in the java exception or your db2 sql output :)

hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I had to put quotes around the arguments: db2 "? SQL302"

Comment: oops! Yes, you are absolutely right, it requires quotes ;) I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 6):

As a general point when using a search engine to search for SQL codes make sure you put the sqlcode e.g. -302 in quote marks - like "-302" otherwise the search engine will exclude all search results including the text 302, since the - sign is used to exclude results.