# while running ds jobs we are getting error as sql state 22001

Tags: sql, datastage, db2-luw

it is showing error executing statement : 'select acc_id,indus,sec from project where acc_id=?'

i run this statement on my db2 and it was successfully executed ,although the result is 0 rows in the memory.

What can be the issue

Comment: Seems like you're missing a `from` clause...

Comment: Is that the full error message? It appears that 22001 is  generic error number and there should be a more specific number that will tell you what the error is. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625336/sqlexception-db2-sql-error-sqlcode-302-sqlstate-22001-sqlerrmc-null

Comment: You are including the SQL STATE, please include also the SQL Error, both together define the true error