# Persiste image file as byte[] on db2

Tags: spring, hibernate, db2

I'm using Spring framework & DB2 as database
i have an entity with image field annotated as follow

```
@Lob
@Type(type="binary")
private byte[] image;
```

or

```
@Lob 
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name="image",columnDefinition="MEDIUMBLOB")
private byte[] image;
```

this not work for db2 and it's return :

**Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null**

Using MySQL i have never seen this error before.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

According to this question:

[SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625336/sqlexception-db2-sql-error-sqlcode-302-sqlstate-22001-sqlerrmc-null)

SQL code -302 means the column in DB2 is too small. Try changing to a bigger BLOB data type.