# Why is JPA throwing SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001 for select query

Tags: sql, spring, db2, spring-data-jpa, db2-luw

I'm trying to frame a select query using JPA repository.

```
select * 
from Foo 
where name = 'testapp'.
```

The "NAME" column is defined as varchar(4). My program throws SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001 for the select operation whereas I get the same query working in  the SQL developer IDE.

Comment: This is the reason:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625336/sqlexception-db2-sql-error-sqlcode-302-sqlstate-22001-sqlerrmc-null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -302, SQLSTATE: 22001, SQLERRMC: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625336/sqlexception-db2-sql-error-sqlcode-302-sqlstate-22001-sqlerrmc-null)

Comment: I know my input variable is larger than the defined column size, Why would select query worry about that? I'm not inserting anything.Like I said this query works just fine in the SQL developer IDE.

Comment: I am having the same issue, have your problem solved?

Comment: Yes some DB's will not allow you to do a select query with the value which is more than the defined column size.